# showing shared layout tabs in page views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

thnx for the help in advance....I hav an mvc project of sign in page in which i have 2 tabs in shared layout page ,one is add user and another is log off tab...now i dont want to show these 2 tabs imidialty when somone open this project. i want to remove these tabs from master view..so that only after a sucesful login that user can see the add user and log of tabs ..what to do to shift these tabs and where to shift these tabs. the tabs are

```
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("UserManagement", "Index", "User")</li>
                 <li>@Html.ActionLink("LogOff", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

Comment: You can specify which `layouts` page to use - generally the login page will be a much cut-back version of the main one.  ie one option is to keep these on your main layout and have a second layout for the login page

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("UserManagement", "Index", "User")</li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("LogOff", "Index", "Home")</li>
}
```